# Why are Entity Framework migration commands handled in the Package Manager Console Window?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget

Surely the Package Manager Console should only be concerned with package installation, updating and removal?

Comment: Those commands are added via a package, so it's all related (same is true to MvcMailer, Scaffolding, etc.). I prefer this over installing specific add-ons for VS (and trying to have all developers on same version).